# How to get text value from div with class name separated?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new with using Jsoup and  i have a problem to get the text value from div with class name text as a string.
This is the string that a want to scrap.

```
<body>
 <div class="details "> 
  <div class="title turquoise2">
    AAC-Olympia 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Correspondentie-adres: 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    Rijdt 37 
   <br /> 6631AP HORSSEN 
   <br /> 0487-541339 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Accommodatie: 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    Sportpark De Polenkamp 
   <br /> Bredestraat 3 
   <br /> 6631BC HORSSEN 
   <br /> 0487-541339 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Opgericht: 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    01-07-2011 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Tenue: 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    Shirt: Wit 
   <br /> Broek: Zwart 
   <br /> Kousen: Zwart 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Regio: 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    Veldregio: Regio 4 veld 
   <br /> Zaalregio: 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Info: 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    Relatienummer: NXTG36Z 
   <br /> Email: 
   <a href="mailto:janberg37@Caiway.nl">janberg37@Caiway.nl</a> 
   <br /> Website: 
   <a href="http://www.aac-olympia.nl">http://www.aac-olympia.nl</a> 
   <br /> District: Oost 
  </div> 
  <div class="subhead turquoise2">
    Klasse(s): 
  </div> 
  <div class="text">
    Klasse za: 
   <br /> Klasse zon: 5e klasse 
   <br /> Klasse zaal: 
   <br /> Junioren: Nee 
   <br /> Pupillen: Nee 
   <br /> Vrouwen: Nee 
   <br /> G-Voetbal: Nee 
  </div> 
  <div class="text"> 
   <a href="http://downloadcentrum.knvb.nl/sportlink/knvb/document/matrix%20verenigingen%20district%20oost?id=55988">Overzicht indeling district Oost</a> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="details details-functionaris"> 
  <div class="title turquoise2">
    AAC-Olympia 
  </div> 
  <div class="voorzitter"> 
  </div> 
  <div class="secretaris"> 
  </div> 
  <div class="penningmeester"> 
  </div> 
  <div class="functionarissen"> 
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
```

I want to get from second div with class name text following information separate, i tried following code but gives me empty string,

```
Element Adres = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("text").get(1);
 String AllTextValue = Adres.text();//This give me all information from the div
```

But i want all 4 text value apart,

```
String firstText =  For this one i have no ieee what i need to do
  String SecondText = Adres.getElementsByTag("br").get(0).text();//Returns Empty value
  String ThirdText  = Adres.getElementsByTag("br").get(1).text();//Returns Empty value
  String FourthText = Adres.getElementsByTag("br").get(2).text();//returns Empty value
```

Can somebody help me.
Thank i lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are looking for is not inside the **br** tag - it is outside:
You use `<br /> abcd` 
For your code to work it should be: `<br>abcd</br>` (which I'm pretty sure is invalid)

You should use lists instead of `<br>` - like so:

```
<div class="text">
    Sportpark De Polenkamp 
   <li> Bredestraat 3 </li>
   <li> 6631BC HORSSEN </li>
   <li> 0487-541339 </li>
</div>
```

Then your logic should work.

Don't forget to loop on the result of `getElementsByTag` instead of hardcoded calls to `.get(x)` since the amount of lines may change.

Just a note - you might need to assign a separate style for these `<li>` elements so the text appears without bullets.

**EDIT:** Since changing the HTML is not possible, the below code "should" work:

`String SecondText = (TextNode)(Adres.getElementsByTag("br").get(0).nextSibling()).text();`

This should get the `br` element, ask for the next `Node` after it - which should be the `TextNode` containing the actual text that you see. Then takes the text from the `TextNode`.

There are two problems with this code:

1. I never used Jsoup - so I have no idea if this would work, I base my answer on my DOM knowledge.
2. This looks like a VERY error-prone code and may fail if/when the website changes the structure - you should make a method for getting the text and handle all the error conditions inside that method.

Check the Jsoup javadocs for how to use their APIs: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is something, this string file i am getting from internet that's means this is how to http looks like from the site, this is the link if you want to check http://www.knvb.nl/clubsenleden/details/NXTG36Z

Answer (score 1):

You could just split the String and go from there. For example:

```
Element Adres = finalDocument.getElementsByClass("text").get(1);

String[] addressParts = Adres.html().split("<br />");

for (String s : addressParts) {
    System.out.println(s.trim());
}
```

Which will output:

```
Sportpark De Polenkamp
Bredestraat 3
6631BC HORSSEN
0487-541339
```

To access individual parts of the address, just call the index (valid from 0 - 3 because there are 4 lines), e.g. `addressParts[1].trim();`. The reason I add `trim()` is to remove the blank space surrounding the String when it is was split originally.